# I have a search function that only works after typing the second letter

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I have a basic messenger react app.

Yet my search function only works after I type the second letter. How is that the case? I am guessing it has to do something with my onChange handler, or maybe e.target.value?

Also when I backspace, my setSearch hook does not clear to an empty "".

The first letter "f" is typed

[image: first letter "f" is typed]

the second letter "u" is typed

[image: second letter "u" is typed]

code

```js
import { Avatar, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './Sidebar.css';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import { RateReviewOutlined } from '@material-ui/icons';
import { SidebarChat } from './SidebarChat';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectUser } from './features/userSlice';
import db, { auth } from './firebase';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import Backdrop from '@material-ui/core/Backdrop';
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  modal: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  paper: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: '2px solid #000',
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
  },
}));

export function Sidebar(props) {
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('chats').onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
      setChats(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      )
    );
  }, []);

  const addChat = () => {
    const chatName = prompt('Please enter a chat name');
    if (chatName) {
      db.collection('chats').add({
        chatName: chatName,
      });
    }
  };

  const searchFunction = (e) => {
    setSearch(e);
    console.log(search);
    console.log(chats);
    const filtered = chats.filter((chat) => {
      return chat.data.chatName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
    });
    // console.log(filtered)
    setChats(filtered);
  };
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <div className="sidebar__header">
        <Avatar
          onClick={handleOpen}
          src={user.photo}
          className="sidebar__avatar"
        />
        <div className="sidebar__input">
          <SearchIcon />
          <input
            placeholder="Search"
            value={search}
            onChange={(e) => searchFunction(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <IconButton variant="outlined" className="sidebar__inputButton">
          <RateReviewOutlined onClick={addChat} />
        </IconButton>
      </div>
      <div className="sidebar__chats">
        {chats.map(({ id, data: { chatName } }) => (
          <SidebarChat key={id} id={id} chatName={chatName} />
        ))}
      </div>

      <Modal
        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
        className={classes.modal}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}
      >
        <Fade in={open}>
          <div className={classes.paper}>
            <h2 id="transition-modal-title">
              Are you sure you want to sign out?
            </h2>
            <button onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Yes</button>
            <button onClick={handleClose}>No</button>
          </div>
        </Fade>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @fortunee thanks for the edit! wow, i have a lot to fix! did you use some sort of eslint?

Comment: Great! I just posted an answer for you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setSearch` is asynchronous by default which means you can get values immediately after they're set.

Performing the filter with `search` will most likely use the previous value of `search`

To prevent this from happening, you can either use the `e` argument you're passing into `searchFunction` in the filter like this

```js
return chat.data.chatName.toLowerCase().includes(e.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: gotcha! this makes sense. essentially with using search instead of E, i was using retrieving the previous state

Comment: React state hooks doesn't accept multiple arguments.

Comment: Good catch @StephanOlsen, the state hook indeed does not allow it, it's only available in class components. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

In the searchFunction you're updating the chats based on the current state of your search value, not the one that you are about to set. You should be iltering your chats based on the argument in your searchFunction *e*.

To clarify further, even though you're calling `setSearch(e)` before you're calling `setChats(filtered)`, these two state updates will happen at the same time. Therefore the state value of `search` is not updated with the new value yet.

Comment: got it, I was using essentially the previous state, instead of using E